# Sharepoint 2010 XSLT Customization Lost on Save

Tags: xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have a page with a XsltListViewWebPart. That is displaying a list with People objects (Person, Department, Email, Phone). I am trying to override the Email to be an actual mailto instead of loading the person card in the mysite.

I am trying to avoid a data grid view as it does not have the sort and add capabilities.

In sharepoint designer I click on one of the TD for the email and click on Customize XSLT and select Customize Item. In the code view i see it changed the web part to have custom XSLT.

I find the display part:

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]" />
```

And change it to:

```
<a href="mailto:{$thisNode/@Email.title}"><xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$thisNode/@Email.title" /></a>
```

In sharepoint designer it updates correctly. I click save and go to preview the page and nothing changed. If I click the refresh page in sharepoint designer the whole XSLT customization is gone (not just the part I changed). The page is checked out to me and even if I save and then check the page back in the customization is gone.

Am I doing it wrong? Is there something that prevents this customization?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the ghost attribute isn't clear. Search for the ddwrt:ghost attribute on your templates.

Try clearing "show_all", "show", or "hide" from the attribute, or remove the attribute altogether.